# How to use existing database and create a single path for an api in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My goal is to run performance tests on multiple different backend server types to find out which ones are most efficient with REST and WebSocket usage and why. As a test setup I've created a test database and a single API path that the API service must provide.

Currently it seems like in other languages (PHP, Python, JavaScript, TypeScript, ...) it's enough to just say "for path X do Y in function <filepath>.<function>" or similar, but in Rails it seems as if the files are not being directly referenced, but rather given keys(?) which Rails then modifies internally and retrieves some file that has some function to execute the request. Additionally it seems that in order to use the database, some models have to be created which work in a similar way, referencing other objects without specifically saying what objects.

It seems that there are some previous questions regarding this, but no matter what I can't seem to get anything working and many tutorials seem to start from the point that Rails must generate new data, instead of using existing data.

**How would I create a simple minimal REST interface with Rails that retrieves (and modifies) cards from**

`GET /users/:userId/cards`

**Where the DB structure (short version) is**

```
User:
  id INT,
  name VARCHAR

Card:
  id INT,
  text VARCHAR

HasPermissions:
  user_id INT,
  card_id INT,
  owner BOOLEAN
```

Rails was initialized using `rails new stresstest --api --minimal -d=postgresql`, no modifications done as everything I did ended up breaking the app or not working at all.

Current Rails version used is 7.0.4.2 and I have no previous experience with Rails, so any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Rails uses the ActiveRecord ORM to interact with a database.  If you want to use Rails as it is designed to be used, you will need to create models based on the ActiveRecord::Base class.

Comment: Rails is a monster of a framework. When running this through python are you using django? When running this through PHP are you using laravel? etc. If not then why are you using rails in ruby? There are much smaller footprint web application infrastructures that can be used to serve a similar purpose e.g. `sinatra` or you could even build a minimal web server with a TCPServer and possibly rack. The question as it stands is very unclear to me but make sure you are comparing apples to apples.

Comment: @engineersmnky yes, in every language I use one of the most common frameworks available. additionally i'm restricted to using "typeless" or "semi-typeless" languages. this restricts the common frameworks to Django, Laravel, ExpressJS, FastAPI, Flask, and Ruby on Rails. Other frameworks work just fine and this is the only one I'm currently having problems with currently

Edit: (basically chosen from Stackoverflow 2022 questionnaires)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I am very unclear on your question here is the basic setup for your request in rails

**config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/users/:id/cards', to: 'cards#index'
end
```

**models/user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :has_permissions
  has_many :cards, through: :has_permissions
end
```

**models/has_permission.rb**

```
class HasPermission < ApplicationRecord # terrible name 
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :card
end
```

**models/card.rb**

```
class Card < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :has_permissions
  has_many :users, through: :has_permissions
end
```

**controllers/cards_controller.rb**

```
class CardsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    @cards = User.find(params[:id]).cards
    render json: @cards
  end 
end
```

Note: There are many steps not included here including

- Installation of the required libraries
- Setting up the database connections in config/database.yml
- Schema generation and/or dumping
- Basically everything else that has anything to do with rails

Comment: Thank you, this has helped me immensely! This code didn't work directly so for future references I had to do the following changes to get this working:
replace CardsController with

class CardController < ApplicationController

    def index

        card = User.find(params[:id]).card

        respond_to do |format|

            format.json { render json: card }

        end

    end

end

and install gem "responders".
Also to each record I had to add the line "self.table_name = '<singular name>'" and in ApplicationController add "include ActionController::MimeResponds"

Comment: @Nuubles glad it helped. You should not have had to make those changes other than the `table_name` assignment

Comment: ah you're correct, just moving respond_to :json into the function index seemed to do the trick. Without the other changes Rails will say that "respond_to is undefined method". Could be something version related or something to do with my minimal installation